# Windows IoT: Async task creation error in a headless (background) program

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, background, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I have a UWP headed app running on my raspberry pi controlling a 8 relays HAT board. It works great. I added the possibility to also control the relays through a web server (I took the model from the "Blinky WebServer" app, it worked. As a final step, I want to convert my initial headed app with UWP UI interface into a headless (background) application. Control of the relays will only be available from the web interface. I created a new headless / background project and added my I/O class that control the relays.
Now that I corrected the main issue based on Michael suggestion, I have issued creating the two main methods (read and write) for my I2Cio class. I need to be able to return a value from the "read" and pass a value to the "write". It is important to notice that the «Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cDevice» "Read" and "Write" methods are neither async methods.
Code is available here: [TestAsync.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtgCJWE6caICiJ5VlMNoVBioNViEzg?e=EWSCfy)

Main task:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

// The Background Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409

namespace TestAsync
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
        I2Cio relay8;
        string result;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            relay8 = new I2Cio();
            result = await relay8.InitRelay8Async();

            // For test purpose, we will loop and set relays
            // according to an incrementing value
            // We will wait 1/2 a second between each value
            for(byte i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                await relay8.WriteRelay8Async(i);
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }

            // The logic handling the relays as well
            // as the interprocess communication with 
            // the web server will come here

            deferral.Complete();

        }
    }
```

I2Cio class with methods (simplified):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.I2c;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace TestAsync
{
    public sealed class I2Cio
    {
        private const string I2C_CONTROLLER_NAME = "I2C1"; //specific to RPi2 or RPi3
        private const byte RELAY8_ADDRESS = 0x27;
        private const byte RELAY8_IN_REG_ADD = 0x00;
        private const byte RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD = 0x01;
        private const byte RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD = 0x03;
        private const byte ALL_IO_OUTPUT = 0x00;

        private static I2cConnectionSettings settings;
        private static string deviceSelector;
        private static DeviceInformationCollection i2cDeviceControllers;
        private static I2cDevice relay8_Board;

        private byte[] readBuffer;

        public IAsyncOperation<string> InitRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await InitRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }

        internal async Task<string> InitRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            try
            {
                settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(RELAY8_ADDRESS)
                {
                    BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode
                };
                deviceSelector = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector(I2C_CONTROLLER_NAME);
                i2cDeviceControllers = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);
                if (i2cDeviceControllers.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("No RPII2C controllers were found on the system");
                }
                relay8_Board = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(i2cDeviceControllers[0].Id, settings);
                if (relay8_Board == null)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Slave address {0} on RPII2C Controller {1} is currently in use by " +
                              "another application. Please ensure that no other applications are using RPII2C.", settings.SlaveAddress, i2cDeviceControllers[0].Id));
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<byte> ReadRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await ReadRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }
        internal Task<byte> ReadRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            byte[] readBuf = new byte[2];
            readBuf[0] = RELAY8_IN_REG_ADD;
            relay8_Board.Read(readBuf);
            return readBuf[1];
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<String> WriteRelay8Async(byte value)
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await WriteRelay8AsyncInternal(value);
            });
        }
        public async Task<String> WriteRelay8AsyncInternal(byte value)
        {
            readBuffer = new byte[2];
            // make all I/O to input / output
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD, ALL_IO_OUTPUT });
            // output the value
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD, value });
            // re-read the value for validation(for future validation if ever required
            //relay8_Board.WriteRead(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD }, readBuffer);
            return null;
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<String> ResetRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await ResetRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }
        public async Task<String> ResetRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            // Set all 8 relays to 0
            // 1 - make all I/O to input / output mode
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD, ALL_IO_OUTPUT });
            // 2 - output the value of 0 to each
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD, 0x00 });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, your recommended reading really help understand.....

Comment: When replicating your suggestion to my (added) "ReadRelay8" and my "WriteRelay8" methods in my I2Cio class, the same error now propagate. Could you please look at the new corrected / adapted code.

Comment: Please note that the task method should be decorated by **private** or **internal**. I have updated my response. @JPRoy

Answer (score 0):

You need to [expose .NET tasks as WinRT asynchronous operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsappdev/exposing-net-tasks-as-winrt-asynchronous-operations). Please refer to following code. BTW, you need define the I2Cio as sealed in headless app.

**Main task:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

// The Background Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409

namespace TestAsync
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
        I2Cio relay8;
        string result;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            relay8 = new I2Cio();
            result = await relay8.InitRelay8Async();

            // For test purpose, we will loop and set relays
            // according to an incrementing value
            // We will wait 1/2 a second between each value
            for (byte i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                await relay8.WriteRelay8Async(i);
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }

            // The logic handling the relays as well
            // as the interprocess communication with 
            // the web server will come here

            deferral.Complete();

        }
    }
}
```

**I2Cio Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.I2c;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace TestAsync
{
    public sealed class I2Cio
    {
        private const string I2C_CONTROLLER_NAME = "I2C1"; //specific to RPi2 or RPi3
        private const byte RELAY8_ADDRESS = 0x27;
        private const byte RELAY8_IN_REG_ADD = 0x00;
        private const byte RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD = 0x01;
        private const byte RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD = 0x03;
        private const byte ALL_IO_OUTPUT = 0x00;

        private static I2cConnectionSettings settings;
        private static string deviceSelector;
        private static DeviceInformationCollection i2cDeviceControllers;
        private static I2cDevice relay8_Board;

        private byte[] readBuffer;

        public IAsyncOperation<string> InitRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await InitRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }

        internal async Task<string> InitRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            try
            {
                settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(RELAY8_ADDRESS)
                {
                    BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode
                };
                deviceSelector = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector(I2C_CONTROLLER_NAME);
                i2cDeviceControllers = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);
                if (i2cDeviceControllers.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("No RPII2C controllers were found on the system");
                }
                relay8_Board = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(i2cDeviceControllers[0].Id, settings);
                if (relay8_Board == null)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Slave address {0} on RPII2C Controller {1} is currently in use by " +
                              "another application. Please ensure that no other applications are using RPII2C.", settings.SlaveAddress, i2cDeviceControllers[0].Id));
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<byte> ReadRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await ReadRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }

        internal Task<byte> ReadRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            byte[] readBuf = new byte[2];
            readBuf[0] = RELAY8_IN_REG_ADD;
            relay8_Board.Read(readBuf);

            return Task.FromResult<byte>(readBuffer[1]);
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<String> WriteRelay8Async(byte relayValue)
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await WriteRelay8AsyncInternal(relayValue);
            });
        }

        private Task<String> WriteRelay8AsyncInternal(byte value)
        {
            readBuffer = new byte[2];
            // make all I/O to input / output
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD, ALL_IO_OUTPUT });
            // output the value
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD, value });
            // re-read the value for validation(for future validation if ever required
            //relay8_Board.WriteRead(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD }, readBuffer);

            return Task.FromResult<string>(string.Empty);
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<String> ResetRelay8Async()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ =>
            {
                return await ResetRelay8AsyncInternal();
            });
        }

        private async Task<String> ResetRelay8AsyncInternal()
        {
            // Set all 8 relays to 0
            // 1 - make all I/O to input / output mode
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_CFG_REG_ADD, ALL_IO_OUTPUT });
            // 2 - output the value of 0 to each
            relay8_Board.Write(new byte[] { RELAY8_OUT_REG_ADD, 0x00 });
            
            return Task.FromResult<string>(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, @ JPRoy 1957, could you please tell me how about this issue? Please feel free let me if it was fixed.

Comment: Michael, thank you again. It works very well and I was able to adapt this approach to all my other classes that need to work headless with HAT hardware (PifaceDigital IO, Sequent Microsystem 8 relays board etc.) This allows me to have a RPI with one headed application (UWP) talking to headless applications (each handling a piece of hardware) and interfacing with their own web interface / server.

Comment: I am now concentrating into having these headless classes being able to handle "interupts" from these various cards.

Comment: @JPRoy1957, please accept my response as answer, it would be helpful for others who encounter the similar issue. Thanks.